# Websockets onMessage Lock

Tags: java, python, websocket

I am using both python and java implementations of a websocket client.  However, since onMessage is asynchronous, it will begin executing immediately, even if there is another function being executed.  How can I ensure that each onMessage function will finish completely before the next message is handled.  Thanks!

EDIT: 
I am subscribing to multiple channels, and regardless of which channel sends a message, my onMessage handler will handle the message.  I need my onMessage handler to fully process each message it receives before it begins to process the next message, but I cannot lose any messages.  I hope this helps to clarify a bit.

Comment: if you are using `javax.websocket`, `session.getBasicRemote().sendText(message, isLast);` sends message synchronous as specified on this [link](https://tyrus.java.net/documentation/1.12/index/lifecycle.html#d0e1022) and [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/PavelBucek/entry/is_websocket_session_really_thread)

Comment: Sending the message isn't the problem, it's receiving the message that I need to synchronize.  So if I get 2 messages in rapid succession, message 1 needs to be fully handled before message 2 starts to be handled if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

It sounds just a concurrent issue. How about this?

```java
private final Object onMessageLock = new Object();

@OnMessage
public void onMessage(String message, Session session)
{
    synchronized (onMessageLock)
    {
        // Handle the message here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, definitely a concurrency issue.  Will I lose any messages that I receive during the lock?

Comment: You won't lose any messages. Other messages that arrive while you are processing a message will wait for the synchronized block to finish. After the synchronized block finishes, one of the waiting messages will acquire the synchronized block and the other waiting messages will again wait for the synchronized block to finish.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I will give this a try and let you know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the solution proposed by Takahiko. It only works based on one client. The messages from different clients will still be processed parallely.

If you want all messages to be processed after the message before has been processed completely (regardless of the client that sent it) you have to make the Lock object static:

```
private static final Object onMessageLock = new Object();
```